# User class entry is disabled in Add Identity dialog box

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, razor-pages, asp.net5

I'm trying to scaffold some identity pages. But while I can select the files to override and select my database context class, the box to select my user class is disabled.

[image: Add Identity Dialog Box]

And attempting to add the scaffolding without setting the user class produces an error.

> There was an error running the selected code generator:
>
> 'Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'Railtrax'.'

This scaffolding feature fails for me about 90% of the time. I don't know why it can't be made more reliable.

Note that I do define my user class.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // ...
}
```

And I reference it in my database context class.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    // ...
}
```

So I don't understand why it won't work. Can anyone see what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

i ran into this error and had to role back the identity Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI to an older version

so it looks like this in the csproj

```
          <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.2" />
            <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.2" />
            <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.2">
    
     
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.6" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="5.0.6" />
       
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.7">
  </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.6" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.6">
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="5.0.2" />
```

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using? This doesn't look like Razor Pages.

Comment: Im using Asp.Net core mvc with .NET 5. The identity library and the ef core version gives those errors sometimes

Answer (score 0):

I have run in the same error as well. It is not due to your User class. Actually, if you enter your Db Context in that window manually pressing "+" it will allow you to find the User class, but you will still get the same error. The issue is with your CodeGenerator. I tried installing different versions of CodeGenerator, but it didn't help.
I did however found a way to scaffold identity that works.
Run the command line in your project folder.

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
```

If you have it installed then run

```
 dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --help
```

to see all the arguments.
or just run

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc MyApplication.Data.ApplicationDbContext --files "Account.Register;Account.Login"
```

-dc showing the path to your application context and --files if you want just specific pages, but I just run without it and then deleted the pages I didn't want.